# Do miniatures for the WH40K Primarchs exist?

Tags: warhammer-40k, miniatures, primarchs

**This is not a question asking where they are/where to get them. This is not a "Let's go shopping" question**

I'm merely wondering *if* there are *any* miniatures for the WH40K Primarchs, and if so, for who (which characters)? To be specific, I should narrow it down to minatures that *can be* bought, or are mass produced. Conversions obviously don't count.

So, are there any Primarch Miniatures available?

Comment: Since WH40k miniatures primarily exist to supply WH40k wargamers, don't you think you'd be more likely to find experts about WH40k miniatures at the [Stack for wargaming](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warhammer-40k) instead of here, even if you're *using* them in an RPG?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Honestly I wasn't too sure about posting the question here, so I asked on meta first, and they told me it was fine. However it would make sense to put it on there as well/instead.

Comment: I do think it's on-topic here, no worries on that count. I'm just dubious it's going to be useful to you posted here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, for some of the primarchs. Forgeworld sells them as part of their Horus Heresy series.

http://www.forgeworld.co.uk/The_Horus_Heresy/HORUS_HERESY_CHARACTER_SERIES

They have eight of the primarchs represented there (as of the time I'm posting this answer). The minis are designed more for display than play (they're expensive too), but they do exist.